# Preventing the Android "long press" to save images

Tags: javascript, android, image, drag

I've written a web-app in HTML and Javascript for iPhone and Android which involves the dragging and dropping images.

You initiate the drag by holding your finger over the image for about a second.  However, Android then pops up the message giving me the option to save the image, set it as wallpaper etc.

How can I prevent Android from doing this?  Is there a metatag I can use?  Some javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Use this event:

```
            $(document).on('contextmenu', function (e) {
                // stop long touch hold from poping up context menus
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has a function to prevent the default action of a browser for the event in question.

In your javascript try:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault

Comment: To what event though?  Nothing seems to fire until you pick your finger up.

Comment: How are you assigning the mouseup/click/longpress event? That is where you define it. All user specified function attached to events will fire before the browsers. In other words, putting event.preventDefault(); in your function for your long press event should fire before androids function. Can we see a little more code?

Comment: All I want is so that when you press and hold on an image the Android dialog doesn't popup.

Comment: ...and as far as I can see there is no longpress event.

Comment: AFAIK you have to preventDefault in the touchstart handler to block the press.

Comment: Not touchstart, that will also block the custom (drag) action.

Answer (score -1):

In your activity that shows the webview, try extending `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`. Then override the `onLongPress(MotionEvent e)` method and doing nothing.

If that doesn't work, you might have to create a custom webview that inherets from webview and overrides onLongPress there.

Or maybe you could try

```
WebView wv =(WebView) findViewById()
wv.setClickable(false)
```

Comment: It's a webpage, not an Android App.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you were writing an android app to interface with your web app. I'm not sure you're going to be able to prevent android from longpressing like that.