# Long press function on Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android-browser

Is there any javascript or html meta to prevent a long press Android Browser action?

Example 1: The [Add to Contact] or [Call] popup when I press for a while a number on a web page.

Example 2: The [Save image] or [View image] popup when I press for a while an image on a web page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for an answer to this question too.

So far I have seen this answer: [Disabling the context menu on long taps on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android)

But in my case (Android Emulator running Froyo) it disables simple clicks too.

My goal is to be able to click on a button (which has an image as background) but if you let the button pressed, you don't get the popup asking to save the image.

This answer: [Preventing the Android "long press" to save images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480709/preventing-the-android-long-press-to-save-images)

Is also incomplete, as it doesn't have a definite solution.